# Appium will not install on my mac. I have quadruple checked everything I can think of

Tags: command-line, terminal, installation, automation, appium

I have spent hours trying to figure out where my install has gone wrong. Sadly I have gotten no closer to solving the issue. I think it may have something to with contextify but I pretty much guess. I also suspect it may be my Nodes but again I am pretty much guessing. Each time I try to install Appium I hit these same errors. Anyone with insight into this issue would be like a super hero at this point.

```
enter code here9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit       (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install:`node-       gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 Exit status 1
/usr/local/lib
└── appium@1.4.13
```

Comment: What is the xcode, python versions you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a old mac machine a while back. 
The reason for the issue in my case is X code and x code command line tools are older. Updating the xcode solved the issue.
Make sure you open the xcode at least once after upgrading.